# Unable to parse XML schema (xsd) on LAN, while able to validate XML with it on my PC

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, xml-parsing, notepad++

If I store all files and shema locally, it I can perfectly validate the `xml` against the schema (`xd`-files) using Notepad++'s XML extension, but when I store them on the company lan, I get an error parsing the schema.

What could cause this difference?

My file `Empty.xml` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aeoi_lux_fatca:AEOI_LUX version="2.0"
    xmlns:aeoi="urn:lu:etat:acd:aeoi_lux:v2.0"
    xmlns:aeoi_fatca="urn:lu:etat:acd:fatca:v2.0"
    xmlns:sfa="urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:stf="urn:oecd:ties:stf:v4"
    xmlns:iso="urn:oecd:ties:isofatcatypes:v1"
    xmlns:aeoi_lux_fatca="urn:lu:etat:acd:aeoi_fatca:v2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="AEOI_FATCA_v2.0.xsd">
    <aeoi_lux_fatca:AEOI_FATCA> 

    </aeoi_lux_fatca:AEOI_FATCA>
</aeoi_lux_fatca:AEOI_LUX>
```

Saving it from Notepad++ in `C:\<someFolder>\`, after copying the schema files there leads to the perfectly normal validation error:

```
ERROR: Element '{urn:lu:etat:acd:aeoi_fatca:v2.0}AEOI_FATCA': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( {urn:lu:etat:acd:aeoi_fatca:v2.0}AEOI_RefId ).
```

Saving it from Notepad++ in `\\<myCompany>\lan\<someFolder>\`, after copying the schema files there leads to an error parsing the schema files:

[image]

The XML schema is the one for [FATCA declarations to the Luxembourg Competent tax Authorities](http://docplayer.net/docview/63/50167260/#file=/storage/63/50167260/50167260.pdf).

Apparently the below reference in `AEOI_LUX_V2.0.xsd`:

```
<xsd:element name="CountryPostal" type="iso:CountryCode_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

fails to resolve to `ISO_COUNTRY_CODES_V1.1.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited  by CTIE (CENTRE DES TECHNOLOGIES DE L'INFORMATION DE L'ETAT) -->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="urn:lu:etat:acd:aeoi:iso_cntry:v1" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.1">
    <!--  ISO 3166 alpha 2 Country Code extended -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="CountryCode_Type">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">ISO-3166 Alpha 2 country codes</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="AF">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>AFGHANISTAN</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            ...
            <xsd:enumeration value="ZWL">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Zimbabwe Dollar: ZIMBABWE</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

It is probably relevant that `isocrstypes_v1.0.xsd` is also defined

- in `isocrstypes_v1.0.xsd` with `targetNamespace="urn:oecd:ties:isocrstypes:v1"` and
- in `isofatcatypes_v1.1.xsd` with `targetNamespace="urn:oecd:ties:isofatcatypes:v1"`.

With the similar schemas for the FACTA declaration to the Belgian CA, I do not have the same problem on the lan folder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is that ISO_COUNTRY_CODES_V1.1.xsd was not imported because its location was not found.

```
<xsd:import namespace="urn:lu:etat:acd:aeoi:iso_cntry:v1" schemaLocation="ISO_COUNTRY_CODES_V1.1.xsd" />
```

should be changed with a correct schemaLocation.

Comment: Should I specify a full URL as schemaLocation? _It is no option to specify a location on my PC or on our LAN: the XML is meath do deliver to en external party._